Are strict higher categories more general than weak higher categories?
I've been exploring the differences between strict and weak higher categories, and I'm curious about their expressiveness and generality. In strict higher categories, morphisms and coherence are explicitly defined at each level, which seems to offer a more comprehensive framework.
My questions:

Do strict higher categories provide a more general framework than weak categories because they allow explicit definitions that can encompass weak behaviors?

How does the complexity of strict categories compare to the flexibility of weak categories in terms of modeling mathematical structures?

Can strict categories inherently express more due to their explicit nature, or does the homotopy equivalence in weak categories offer a fundamentally different form of expressiveness?

If strict higher categories are able to capture more fine grained detail that is lost in homotopical approach, why is it less used? Is it because working with strict higher category theory would uncover more details, but it would be too hard?



It is exactly the opposite; strict higher categories are much less general and they express much less. Famously there is no strict $3$-groupoid which models the homotopy $3$-type of $S^2$ (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/269172/why-grothendiecks-homotopy-hypothesis-is-so-difficult).

but can we explicitly defined what kind of morphisms we want level by level in weak higher categories?

why the downvotes? I am just trying to understand the topic

@PanMrož There is a nice concise discussion of the difference in generality between weak higher categories and strict higher categories, and motivating examples of weak higher categories which fail to be strict, in Leinster's "Higher Operads, Higher Categories" book, in the "Alert" remark on pg. xv (page 23 in the arXiv PDF): https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0305049

As Qiaochu has explained in the comments, strict higher categories are less general: You can pass from strict to weak higher categories, but many important $\infty$-categories (for example the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid of a space) only exist in the weak world and do not lift to the strict world.
While it should in principle be possible to give combinatorial descriptions with explicit coherences of weak $n$-categories (this seems to be what you asked for in your follow-up comment), note that this can't be easy: The free weak $n$-groupoid on one object with a nontrivial $m$-automorphism looks like (the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid of) $\tau_{\leq n} S^m$, in particular it has $\pi_k S^m$ for $k\leq m$ as the $k$-endomorphisms of the object. So for example, any combinatorial description of, say, weak $7$-categories, must somehow reproduce things like $\pi_7(S^4)=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/12$. In fact, the fundamental $\infty$-groupoid of $\tau_{\leq n} X$ for any finite CW complex $X$ can be interpreted as $n$-groupoid given by an explicit generators-and-relations description, so a suitably effective combinatorial description of $n$-categories more or less completely subsumes homotopy theory "up to degree $n$".

For the question about "definition of composition" it might be worth mentioning the notion of "algebraic quasicategory" which has some features of both worlds (though is essentially unusable/unused in practice)
